# Global Platform CRS and card specific commands

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I'm trying to read some data from the secure element in the SIM of a global platform 2.2 card.

My SELECT command of the applet is successful 90,00 with some PDOL data in the response. However when I send Get Processing Options it returns 6D00. It seems the Security Domain is still in charge and does not understand the GPO command.

My investigation says applet specific commands needs to go over a secure channel, while the CRS runs on the basic channel. Is this requirement true even if the card is not being accessed over the contactless interface?

Answer (score 0):

First of all verify that your applet must be selected on same I/O interface and the same logical channel on which you are sending the command.

The status word '6D00' shows that the command sent over another applet or SD that does not understand it instead of secure channel initiation requirement.

And yes if you are communicating with secured card like and Secure element then you need to initiate scp session.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT APDU` should be sent first with correct [AID](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/211-emv-aid-rid-pix).
If AID belongs to the EMV card, response should come with status SW 90 00 with data area. Processing Options Data Object List in data area should be properly parsed and `GET PROCESSING OPTIONS` should be constructed with required parameters (Terminal 
 Transaction Qualifiers,Amount, Authorized , Unpredictable Number etc.)

Try this [TLV utilities](https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/) and see the options list:

```
9F38 Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL)
    9F66049F02069F37045F2A029A03
```